# Mapbox CustomCSS styles converted to GL Styles: pirates, pencil

Tags: react-native, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, react-native-mapbox-gl

I used to work with `react-leaflet` to build maps, and now I am on a `react-native` project where I use `@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps`.

With `react-leaflet`, I could use some [raster tile](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#raster-tiles) url, such as `https://api.mapbox.com/v4/{mapbox_id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={access_token}` which allowed me to use some of `mapbox_id`s such as [`mapbox.pirates`](https://openmaptiles.org/styles/#pirates), [`mapbox.pencil`](https://openmaptiles.org/styles/#pencil) or [other quite cool available ones](https://openmaptiles.org/styles/#pencil).

With `@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps` [a styleURL is needed](https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/blob/master/docs/MapView.md#props) which [looks likes](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#mapbox-styles) `mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11` for instance.

It seems that using raster tiles url is not something we can do within styles. Does somebody knows a way to use good old styled maps ? Or does an open sourced map with old styles exists ? I didn't see any, maybe it is hidden somewhere ?

I could find a Mapbox Style created with Mapbox Studio Classic for the Pirates style, but it is written in CartoCSS and [this is not compatible with the new version of Mapbox Studio](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-studio-classic/blob/mb-pages/docs/studio-classic-manual/06-studio-classic-transition.md#can-i-use-mapbox-studio-classic-styles-in-mapbox-studio), the style needs to be completely re-written.
Does anyone know a good and easy way for a beginner to re-write the style in minutes/hours and not in days ? Or did anyone do the job before, and open-sourced it somewhere ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the example at https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/map-tiles/, you can add a style json which has a single raster layer and point this to Mapbox's tile URL for pencil or pirates.

Alternatively there are Mapbox GL designer styles which may suite at https://www.mapbox.com/gallery/ and https://blog.mapbox.com/designing-the-vintage-style-in-mapbox-studio-9da4aa2a627f

Comment: thanks for the tip, especially the link to the `map-tiles` docmentation on mapbox.com. Combined to [this github issue](https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/issues/6), I could almost make it work !